# AngularJS Directive - Populating ng-click From Model Property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm running into an issue where I cannot seem to make my ng-click event recognize the function tied to one of its properties. Here is my code:

Service:

```
factory.getContextMenuItems = function(message) {
    var items = [];
    var href;

    href = '#';
    items.push({
        href: href,
        iconClass: "sentIcon",
        hasIcon: true,
        clickEvent: navigationFactory.navigate(message)
    });
    return items;
}
```

Main View - The controller tied to this view calls the above factory to get the data:

```
<div id="readMessage" class="readMessage" data-ng-model="model.message" role="region" aria-label="Message Content" aria-live="polite">
    <div class="senderContextArea" data-webuser-context-menu 
    data-menu-items="model.message.contextMenu" 
    data-from-name="{{model.message.from}}" 
    data-ng-if="model.message.contextMenu.length > 0"></div>
</div>
```

Directive Template:

```
<ul class="contextMenu" role="menu">
    <li data-ng-repeat="item in menuItems">
        <a href="{{item.href}}" title="{{item.title}}" role="menuitem" target="_blank" data-ng-click="{{item.clickEvent}}">
            <span data-ng-if="item.hasIcon" class="{{item.iconClass}}"></span> {{item.text}}
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Directive:

```
(function(app) {
    app.directive('menu', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {menuItems: '=', fromName: '@'},
            templateUrl: '/contextMenu.html'
       }
    });
})(angular.module('app'));
```

All my other attributes are wired up properly. Everything else I expect other than the click event itself is wiring up fine. There must be a step I'm missing.

Comment: Is navigationFactory available in scope?

Comment: where is controller defined for this and have u included your service/factory dependency in your controller and using that method for ng-click ?

Comment: Its available in the scope of the factory that gets the context menu items. That isn't where the code is coughing up. The JS just flat out does not recognize {{item.clickEvent}}.

Comment: Get rid of the curly brackets in data-ng-click

Comment: This markup template corresponds to a directive and not a controller. I can edit and post that as well. Since everything else wired up nicely, didn't think I would need to.

Comment: @jackyrudetsky - I tried that and it just rendered as the literal "item.clickEvent"

Comment: You need to use '&' to bind behaviors in a directive.  Please post the directive code as well.

Comment: directive code is posted. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: Right the brackets don't need to be in the ng-click property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try wrapping your `navigationFactory.navigate(message)` with an anonymous function like this:

```
function(){navigationFactory.navigate(message);}
```

and in your ng-click exchange with `item.clickEvent()` without `{{}}`

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. ng-click does not need to be wrapped in brackets. Thanks.